# Como cambiar color de cursor en un EditText - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, textfield

He intentado cambiar el cursor de este EditText, pero solo lo he logrado usando la propiedad ***textCursorDrawable***, la cual es solo permitida para la Api29 en adelante. ¿Hay una forma de hacer el mismo cambio para las versiones anteriores?

[image: REF]

Comment: ¿Cómo le estás asignando el color al `textCursorDrawable`?

Comment: Usando un drawable y dandole color, pero esto solo funciona para la api 29 en adelante.

Comment: ¿Probaste creando un shape en vez de asignándoselo en vez de darle un color?

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado, prueba a crear un shape y a usarlo como cursor.

El shape en el fichero xml edit_text_cursor.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
</shape>
```

El EditText:

```
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_text_cursor" />
```